# Google Contextual Gadget to get FROM_PERSONAL and TO_PERSONAL

Tags: javascript, xml, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I need help to resolve the issue.
I was referring the google gadget API but not able to get the FROM_PERSONAL and TO_PERSONAL. Can any one please let me know the whats wrong with setting. I refer Google Contextual Gadget API doc and Javascript API

I tried to Google and follow the several demo's from web but still facing the same issue. :(

```
<Extension id="SenderEmailExtractor" type="contextExtractor">
<Name>Sender name Extractor</Name>
<Url>google.com:SenderEmailExtractor</Url>
<Param name="message_sender" value=".*"/>
<Triggers ref="GetTicket"/>
<Scope ref="ticket_creator"/>
<Container name="mail"/>
</Extension>
```

/* And Javascript code as bellow */

```
matches = google.contentmatch.getContentMatches();
for (var match in matches) {
  for (var key in matches[match]) {

    if( key =='sender_email')
    {
      var sender_email_id = matches[match][key];
    }

    if(key =='message_sender')
    {
      var sender_name = matches[match][key];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After longtime research I found,If you have non-admin account then it will take time to configure your account.

Went to Google Apps Marketplace SDK options.

Checked the Gmail contextual gadget extension added below extension to Enables app to work with Gmail Contextual Gadgets.

1) Enabled  extension.
Extractor URL - google.com:SenderEmailExtractor
Gadget URL - (live web access URL for gadget.xml)
Param Name - sender_email
Param Value - .*
Scopes - Mail – Sender Address , Sneder Name.

2) Enabled  extension.
Extractor URL - google.com:RecipientEmailExtractor
Gadget URL - (live web access URL for gadget.xml)
Param Name - recipient_email
Param Value - .*
Scopes - Mail – To Recipient Address  To Recipient Name

3) Enabled  extension.
Extractor URL - google.com:RecipientToEmailExtractor
Gadget URL - (live web access URL for gadget.xml)
Param Name - recipient_to_email
Param Value - .*
Scopes - Mail – To Recipient Address  To Recipient Name